# Shell script, use awk for diagonal word search

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, diagonal

Im looking for a way to get al the diagonal combinations from this block of letters:

```
a b c d e f 
h i j k l m 
o p q r s t 
v w x y z a 
c d e f g h 
j k l m n o
```

i have this: `awk '{++f; print $(f + 0)}' file.txt`

but that only gets me ( if i can increase, f + 0, somehow with 1, 6times ):

```
a i q y g o
b j r z h
c k s a
d l t
e m 
f
```

and i need the other half to.. like this(does not have to be in this order:

```
a i q y g o
h p x f n
b j r z h
o w e m
c k s a
v d l
d l t
c k
e m
j 
f
```

Comment: So what is the full desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
perl -lane'
  push @r, [@F];
END {
  for my $n (0 .. $#r) {
    my (@x,@y);
    for (0 .. $#r) {
      push @x, $r[$n+$_][$_];
      push @y, $r[$_][$n+$_];
    }
    print "@x";
    print "@y" if $n;
  }
}
' file
```

output

```
a i q y g o
h p x f n
b j r z h
o w e m
c k s a
v d l
d l t
c k
e m
j
f
```

Comment: Do you maby know a way to edit your code and also get al the possible 2,3,4,5,6 letter words from this output ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [GNU datamash](http://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/):

```
$ datamash -t' ' transpose < file
a h o v c j
b i p w d k
c j q x e l
d k r y f m
e l s z g n
f m t a h o
```

Comment: @Brutalized: You must install it first, see http://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/download/

Comment: I would like to avoid that

Comment: i can get the same result by using a for loop but i was looking for a more efficient way ( without installing something, good solution though! tnx)

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for an array.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

# Print diagonals from a square of text. 
# This script has no error checking.
# Written by PM 2Ring 2014.10.13

{
    for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) 
        a[NR,i] = $i
}

END{
    for(i=1; i<=NR; i++)
    {
        for(j=1; i+j-1<=NR; j++)
            printf "%s ", a[i+j-1, j]
        print ""
        if (i == 1) 
            continue
        for(j=1; i+j-1<=NR; j++)
            printf "%s ", a[j, i+j-1]
        print ""
    }
}
```

---

Here's a version of the above code that stores each diagonal word in an array.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

# Print diagonals from a square of text. 
# This script has no error checking.
# Written by PM 2Ring 2014.10.13

{
    for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) 
        a[NR,i] = $i
}

END{
    k = 1
    for(i=1; i<=NR; i++)
    {
        word = ""
        for(j=1; i+j-1<=NR; j++)
            word = word a[i+j-1, j]
        words[k++] =  word

        if (i == 1) 
            continue

        word = ""
        for(j=1; i+j-1<=NR; j++)
            word = word a[j, i+j-1]
        words[k++] = word   
    }

    numwords = k
    for (k=1; k<numwords; k++)
        print words[k]
}
```

**output**

```
aiqygo
hpxfn
bjrzh
owem
cksa
vdl
dlt
ck
em
j
f
```

Printing the orthogonal diagonals, eg 'flrxdj', is left as an exercise for the reader.

...

Here's a function that prints all the subwords in a given word.

```awk
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

# Print subwords of a given word 
# Written by PM 2Ring 2014.10.13

function print_subwords(s,  i, j, len)
{
    len = length(s)
    for (i=1; i<=len; i++)
    {
        print "Length:", i
        for (j=1; i+j-1 <= len; j++)
            print substr(s, j, i)
    }
}

BEGIN{
    print_subwords("ABCD") 
}
```

**output**

```
Length: 1
A
B
C
D
Length: 2
AB
BC
CD
Length: 3
ABC
BCD
Length: 4
ABCD
```

Comment: Do you maby know a way to edit your code and also get al the possible 2,3,4,5,6 letter word combinations ?

Comment: I do, but I think you should try to do that for yourself. If you get stuck, post your code (preferably in a new question) and we'll try to help. But I'll give you a few hints.